# XSLT How to use "line" char ('-') as parameter

Tags: function, xslt, concatenation

I have implemented this function (template):

```
<xsl:template name="insSepToFechaHost">
    <xsl:param name="fecha" />
    <xsl:param name="sep" />
    <xsl:variable name="anio" select="substring($fecha,1,4)" />
    <xsl:variable name="mes" select="substring($fecha,5,2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="dia" select="substring($fecha,7,2)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($anio,$sep,$mes,$sep,$dia)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and I call it...

```
<fechaOperacion>
<xsl:call-template name="insSepToFechaHost">
    <xsl:with-param name="fecha" select="$datOperacion/STDR2_FECOPE" />
    <xsl:with-param name="sep" select="-" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

The function is simple, value to receive is like this '20130502' and the function will return '2013-05-02', '2013/05/02', '2013*05*02', etc... (depends of 'sep' value). But, I don't know why it doesn't work?... I've noticed if I change the param 'sep' as a constant, the function works..

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat($anio,'-',$mes,'-',$dia)"/>
```

Could you please give some advices?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually passing in a constant string for `sep` at the moment.

Try changing this line

```
<xsl:with-param name="sep" select="-" />
```

To this instead

```
<xsl:with-param name="sep" select="'-'" />
```